# SUM values under MONTH/YEAR conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs, sumproduct

I have the following table

```
╔════════════╦════════════╦════════╦════════╗
║ Booking    ║ Check-in   ║ Dif    ║ Status ║
╠════════════╬════════════╬════════╬════════╣
║ 25-09-2018 ║ 19-05-2019 ║ 234.15 ║ OK     ║
╠════════════╬════════════╬════════╬════════╣
║ 26-09-2018 ║ 05-05-2019 ║ 281.21 ║ OK     ║
╠════════════╬════════════╬════════╬════════╣
║ 26-09-2018 ║ 18-05-2019 ║ 264.11 ║ OK     ║
╠════════════╬════════════╬════════╬════════╣
║ 01-10-2018 ║ 19-06-2019 ║ 260.42 ║ CL     ║
╠════════════╬════════════╬════════╬════════╣
║ 01-10-2018 ║ 18-05-2019 ║ 228.16 ║ OK     ║
╚════════════╩════════════╩════════╩════════╝
```

I have been trying to create a sumproduct formula that will sum "Dif" if the month and year of check-in and booking date are the same under the condition that status is ok.

The output table I want to generate has the following form:

```
╔══════════════════╦═════╦══════╗
║ Booking/Check-in ║ May ║ June ║
╠══════════════════╬═════╬══════╣
║ September        ║     ║      ║
╠══════════════════╬═════╬══════╣
║ October          ║     ║      ║
╚══════════════════╩═════╩══════╝
```

The formula I used and received the error was:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--('Data'!$D$2:$D$5="OK")*(MONTH('Data'!$A$2:$A$5)=MONTH($A2))*(YEAR('Data'!$A$2:$A$5)=YEAR($A2))*(MONTH('Data'!$B$2:$B$5)=MONTH(B$1))*(YEAR('Booking data'!$B$2:$B$5)=YEAR(B$1))*('Data'!$C$2:$C$5))
```

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Instead of "the following **form**", could you detail the **exact** table you want as output from that first table? I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean by sum since you seem to have repeated both columns and rows, it seems to me that your "sum" would simply be to put the value from table 1 at the correct intersection in table 2. Can you explain further?

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. You are right. The exact table I want as an output is the second one (I had to edit the original post). Just to give you a brief example, B2 should be equal to: 234.15+281.21+264.11 i.e. the sum of Dif under the conditions that status="OK", the month and year of booking and check-in date is equal to the ones of respective x and y axis. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try `=SUMPRODUCT(('Data'!$D$2:$D$5="OK")*(MONTH('Data'!$A$2:$A$5)=MONTH($A2))*(YEAR('Data'!$A$2:$A$5)=YEAR($A2))*(MONTH('Data'!$B$2:$B$5)=MONTH(B$1))*(YEAR('Data'!$B$2:$B$5)=YEAR(B$1))*('Data'!$C$2:$C$5)*1)` It seems that the first **YEAR** function in your original formula was referring to Column `B2:B5` on another sheet `Booking Data` rather than the `Data` sheet where all other references are sitting in.

Answer (score 1):

What you need for this is PIVOT TABLES:

> **[Pivot Tables](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-pivottable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576)**

I got this data, and the output is a Pivot Table:

Data:

[image]

Output:

[image]

My setup for my Pivot table:

1. `Booking` field to ROWS
2. `Check-in` field to COLUMNS
3. Both fields (`Booking` and `Check-in`) are **grouped by MONTHS** (check [Group or ungroup data in a PivotTable](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/group-or-ungroup-data-in-a-pivottable-c9d1ddd0-6580-47d1-82bc-c84a5a340725))
4. `Status` field to FILTERS and **set it up to show only OK values**.
5. `Dif` field to VALUES
6. I also deactivated grand totals and subtotals (this is optional)

Hope this helps. In the output, June is not shown because there is no OK values in june to sum up

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I am aware that I can use Pivot Tables, nonetheless I need to generate the required results using the SUMPRODUCT formula.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Solutions]

I think the month name in your output table is actually a date formatted as full month name.

If you only want to sum by month name rather than actual date, here is one way of doing that:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((TEXT($A$2:$A$6,"mmmm")=$A9)*(TEXT($B$2:$B$6,"mmmm")=B$8)*($D$2:$D$6="OK")*($C$2:$C$6))
```

If you want to sum by actual date (taking into account the year component), then you can use the following formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((TEXT($A$2:$A$6,"MMM-YY")=TEXT($A13,"MMM-YY"))*(TEXT($B$2:$B$6,"MMM-YY")=TEXT(B$12,"MMM-YY"))*($D$2:$D$6="OK")*($C$2:$C$6))
```

Amend the cell references as needed. Cheers :)

> The trick is to use **TEXT** function to convert the dates into a text format, in my example is "MMM-YY", so they can be compared easily without the need of comparing month and year component seperately. Sadly the **EOMONTH** function does not support array calculations otherwise the solution could be slightly simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the month names in your output table are dates of the first of the month/year formatted to show as a full month name, you can use `SUMIFS`:

I converted the data table into a **Table** so as to be able to use structured references, which I find more understandable in complex formulas:

```
=SUMIFS(Table1[[Dif]:[Dif]],Table1[[Status]:[Status]],"OK",Table1[[Booking]:[Booking]],">="&$F2,Table1[[Booking]:[Booking]],"<=" &EOMONTH($F2,0),Table1[[Check-in]:[Check-in]],">="&G$1,Table1[[Check-in]:[Check-in]],"<="&EOMONTH(G$1,0))
```

We determine the date by ensuring that the Booking and/or Check-in dates occur in the same month as the output table.  This will, of course, ensure that the month and year are the same.

The `G$1` and `$F2` addresses will depend on the location of the output table.  But once you enter the formula in, for example `G2`, you can fill/drag it down and across and the references should automatically adjust.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your replies. I figured out what I should do. Please, find below the formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--('Data'!$D$2:$D$5="OK"),(MONTH('Data'!$A$2:$A$5)=MONTH($A2))*(YEAR('Data'!$A$2:$A$5)=YEAR($A2))*(MONTH('Data'!$B$2:$B$5)=MONTH(B$1))*(YEAR('Data'!$B$2:$B$5)=YEAR(B$1))*'Data'!$C$2:$C$5)
```